# Como selecionar mais de um arquivo txt com C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, arquivo

Estou escrevendo uma aplicação em C# que precisa receber mais de 1 arquivo de texto e exibir o `Filename` deles em um `MessageBox` individual para cada.

Minha dúvida está nessa importação dos arquivos, estava usando `OpenFileDialog` para selecionar o arquivo, mas ele não funciona se eu selecionar mais de 1 arquivo de texto, abaixo o código usado:

```
private void btnSelecionarArquivos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog fDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        fDialog.Filter = "Arquivos Texto|*.txt";
        fDialog.Title = "Selecione os Arquivos";
        if(fDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(fDialog.FileName.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta configurar a propriedade [`Multiselect`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.multiselect?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_OpenFileDialog_Multiselect). O resultado será retornado na propriedade [`Filenames`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filenames?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_FileDialog_FileNames) (plural) que é um *array* de `strings`:

```
private void btnSelecionarArquivos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    OpenFileDialog fDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    fDialog.Multiselect = true;
    fDialog.Filter = "Arquivos Texto|*.txt";
    fDialog.Title = "Selecione os Arquivos";
    if(fDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) MessageBox.Show(fDialog.FileNames.Aggregate((atual, proximo) => atual + ", " + proximo));
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/SelectFile.cs).

Comment: Show amigo, funcionou, obrigado!!!